# React best way to pre-measure element with auto width

Tags: reactjs, measure

I have bootstrap button group, each button with dynamic with based on it's content. I need to move buttons to dropdown menu if they didn't fit to block size. Is should be recalculated on each resize event. What is the best way to pre render button group and measure how many buttons fit to screen  and avoid performance issues?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvqit.png)

Comment: This sounds like a job for CSS, is there a reason you want to explicitly set the width using JavaScript instead of using a percentage-based CSS width, or with flexbox?

Comment: Because content always dynamic. I don't know how many buttons should be rendered and don't know their labels.

Comment: This question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569886/wrap-overflowing-lis-into-dropdown-list