# jQuery Change click function to mouse over on desktop and click on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var h = 30;
var val = 0;

$('.click').click(function() {
  if ($('ul').hasClass('show')) {
    $('ul').removeClass('show');
    $('ul li.menu-item').removeClass('drop')
    return;
  }
  val = 0;
  $('ul li.menu-item').each(function() {
    var of = $(this).offset().top - $('ul').offset().top;
    if ( of > 20) {
      $(this).addClass('drop');
      $(this).css('top', 'calc(100% + ' + val + 'px)');
      val += h;
    }
    $('ul').addClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.show {
  overflow: visible;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 8px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

li.drop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 102%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

li.drop::after {
  content: none;
}

.click {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -65px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item">menu1</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu2</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu3</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu4</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu5</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu6</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu7</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu8</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu9</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu10</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu11</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu12</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu13</li>
  <li class="menu-item">menu14</li>
</ul>
<div class="click"></div>
```

The menu I'm working on should wrap overflowing menu items into a dropdown list similar to the one in this link ([How to wrap overflowing menu items into dropdown list to create a responsive navigation menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569886/how-to-wrap-overflowing-menu-items-into-dropdown-list-to-create-a-responsive-nav)). However, I need assistance switching the click function on desktop computers to mouseover, and the default click function on mobile devices. If a user clicks anywhere outside of the dropdown's button on a mobile device, it should automatically close. How's that possible?

**Codepen:**
**https://codepen.io/bootstrap007/pen/GRPMdgm**

Comment: Hi @bootstrap, to use different events for different devices or environments, you need to first write a code to determine the device or environment like it is a Desktop or it is mobile. Then you can put your logic inside it like --- if(environment === desktop) { bind mouse hover event } else { bind click event code}

Comment: Hi @bootstrap, 
(2) To hide dropdown menu outside click - you need to check it's parent element, if clicked element or link's parent element is menu then keep open dropdown else close that menu. 
You can also close it on click of any menu item.
Example : https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/EWWojp?editors=1010

Comment: To detect and determine whether a device is Mobile or Desktop: 
(1) https://medium.com/geekculture/detecting-mobile-vs-desktop-browsers-in-javascript-ad46e8d23ce5 (2) https://dev.to/timhuang/a-simple-way-to-detect-if-browser-is-on-a-mobile-device-with-javascript-44j3